# Google Map InfoWindow is too wide

Tags: css, google-maps, infowindow

On click of a marker, I'm opening an InfoWindow on a Google Map.

The code is like this:

```
var point = 
    new GLatLng(
        mPointSet.points[i].lat,
        mPointSet.points[i].long);

var marker = new GMarker(point);

function createMarker(marker, message)
{
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(
            $("#marker-popup-template").html());
    });
}

createMarker(marker);

mBigMap.addOverlay(marker);
```

The problem is, even though the  that the InfoWindow is being populated with has been styled to be 200 px max-width, the InfoWindow *still* renders too wide, at around 400 px.

Is there a way to make it smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [maxWidth](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions.maxWidth).

```
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(
    $("#marker-popup-template").html(),
    { maxWidth: 400 }
);
```